# Python TKinter Menu with Options

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I have a code in Python that has various options such as Add, Remove, Search etc...
Can i make a GUI using Tkinter that basically when it runs, it shows buttons with all the options, then when you click for example "Add" it appears a input box for the user to Add a new value, then goes back to the initial page etc... I do this very easily in Java using JOptionPane(not with buttons tho).. I tried searching for Menus in Tkinter but is not the ones i want (its the ones that appear on the top left of the page)...

Appreciate all the help

Comment: yes, that is all possible.

Comment: How? any links?

Comment: "How" is way too broad for stackoverflow. You need to start by working through a tkinter tutorial.

Comment: How can i talk to you explaining what i got so far and what not? i know how to do buttons, input boxes and all the basics. I just cant figure how to create a new windows whenever i click on buttons. I'm also having a problem to use methods that are in a different class from the class GUI is in

Comment: if you know how to do button then you should know `command=` in button. To create second window use `tkinter.Toplevel()` similar to `tkinter.Tk()`

Comment: I have a box with input for the user. When the user clicks "save" it should call a function that is in another class passing the input of the user as an argument. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think a quick google search would have found these answers. But anyway here are a few links to help you.

[Playlist of TKinter tutorial for future use (Object Oriented)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HjNHATw6XgY&index=1&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDclKx-QpC9wntnURXVJqLyk)
 
(His youtube channel and his site are amazing for learning the basic and advanced Python( Games, Machine Learning, Website, etc.)

[Add buttons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y6cir7P3YUk&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDclKx-QpC9wntnURXVJqLyk&index=3)

[Input](http://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_entry_widgets.php) (Also great website)

[Popup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TQJRM8hIbXA&index=12&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDclKx-QpC9wntnURXVJqLyk)

## Example code

Like I said, you could quickly google these and find an answer.

```
from tkinter import *
import sys

class popupWindow(object):
    def __init__(self,master):
        top=self.top=Toplevel(master)
        self.l=Label(top,text="Add a new value")
        self.l.pack()
        self.e=Entry(top)
        self.e.pack()
        self.b=Button(top,text='Ok',command=self.cleanup)
        self.b.pack()
    def cleanup(self):
        self.value=self.e.get()
        self.top.destroy()
class mainWindow(object):
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master=master
        self.b=Button(master,text="Add!",command=self.popup)
        self.b.pack()
        # Check python shell for the output
        self.b2=Button(master,text="Print Value From Input",command=lambda: sys.stdout.write(self.entryValue()+'\n'))
        self.b2.pack()

    def popup(self):
        self.w=popupWindow(self.master)
        self.master.wait_window(self.w.top)

    def entryValue(self):
        return self.w.value




root = Tk()
m = mainWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Actually, none of those are useful. I clearly said i wanted to click on buttons, and when i clicked , it would open another window to do actions..

Comment: I edited my original answer to show example code. On stackoverflow, no one is going to do your work for you, we just provide help after you have tried your best.

Answer (score 0):

@Manny102030
I got this code. basically what i want is to insert a Node in a Tree with the value that the user inputs in the Tkinter. I dont know if the value the user is inputting is actually being inserted because i cant figure how to call the function that i created to print the Tree (the function is also in the class BST).
What i did was call the BST in the mainWindow class, then in the BST i call the window for the user to input, and when he clicks "Ok" it calls the function insert. Then in the insert i pass the value from the user to create the node to put in the tree... Any improvements/any ideas on how to call the function to print the tree?

```
class mainWindow(object):
        def __init__(self,master):
                self.master = master
                self.b=Button(master,text="Add value",command=self.popupAdd)
                self.b.pack()
        def popupAdd(self):
                self.w=BST(self.master)
                self.master.wait_window(self.w.top)
class BST(object):
        def __init__(self,master):
                self._root = None
                top=self.top=Toplevel(master)
                self.l=Label(top,text="Add a new value")
                self.l.pack()
                self.e=Entry(top)
                self.e.pack()
                self.b=Button(top,text='Ok',command=self.insert)
                self.b.pack()
        def insert(self):
                novo = No(self.e.get()) #insert value in Node
                if self._root == None:
                        self._root = novo
                else:
                        pai = self._root
                        temp = self._root
                        while temp != None:
                                if valor > temp.getValor():
                                        pai = temp
                                        temp = temp.getRight()
                                elif (valor < temp.getValor()):
                                        pai = temp
                                        temp = temp.getLeft()
                                else:
                                        temp = None
                                        print("Value Already exists")
                        if valor > pai.getValor():
                                pai.setRight(novo)
                        elif valor < pai.getValor():
                                pai.setLeft(novo)
                self.top.destroy()
        def printTree(self, root):
                if root != None:
                        self.printTree(root.getLeft())
                        print(" " + str(root.getValor()), end="")
                        self.printTree(root.getRight())
```

Comment: OP wanted this. Add a new value, then go back to the initial page, etc.